# What is the correct way to get the contents of a folder in a Core 2.1 API project?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .Net Core 2.1 API with a folder called "Templates" in the root of the project. From inside of a controller action, I want to load the contents of a file in the "Templates" folder except I'm seeing all kinds of ways to get the web API's base directory and none of them seem to either work or appear to be exactly as straight-forward as it should seem to be.

What is the best practice, correct way to do this?

(Edit: note that what I have found so far is for RC1, RC2, and Net Core console applications and none of these methods or examples are pertinent or work for a Core 2.1 Web API project)

Comment: I've submitted an answer but the most succinct way of summarizing it is `AppContext.BaseDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

You use the `AppContext.BaseDirectory` property combined with the folder you create and make sure that the contents of that folder are copied to output.